# Update Angular 5 to Angular 6 error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5, angular2-template, angular6

I just updated from angular 5 to angular 6 and I am facing an issue with angular animations.

I did the standard upgrade

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
ng update @angular/core
npm install rxjs-compat (most project probably need this)
ng serve
```

I also updated my codebase based on the official upgrade guide (https://update.angular.io/) from 5.2 to 6, but there was one error, which I could not figure out.

```
ERROR in src/app/dispute-center/shared/services/dispute-store-service.ts(1,22): error TS2305: Module '"/var/www/html/xxx-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'transition'.

src/app/profile/profile-payments-and-billing/profile-payments-and-billing.component.ts(1,28): error TS2305: Module '"/var/www/html/xxx-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'trigger'.

src/app/profile/profile-payments-and-billing/profile-payments-and-billing.component.ts(1,37): error TS2305: Module '"/var/www/html/xxx-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'state'.

src/app/profile/profile-payments-and-billing/profile-payments-and-billing.component.ts(1,44): error TS2305: Module '"/var/www/html/xxx-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'style'.

src/app/profile/profile-payments-and-billing/profile-payments-and-billing.component.ts(1,51): error TS2305: Module '"/var/www/html/xxx-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'transition'.

src/app/profile/profile-payments-and-billing/profile-payments-and-billing.component.ts(1,63): error TS2305: Module '"/var/www/html/xxx-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'animate'.
```

I imagine it's because the animation module imports have moved, but under which package have they moved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the breaking changes section of the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2018-05-03) for v6:

`core: it is no longer possible to import animation-related functions from @angular/core. All animation symbols must now be imported from @angular/animations.`

So you need to update your imports for `trigger`, `transition`, `animate`, `trigger`, `state`, etc to be from `@angular/animations` instead of `@angular/core`.

Comment: Save my day. Thank you